# Gulp concat and require path

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

I have a problem with gulp-concat. I'm trying to concate all my js files in a single file, let's say, dist/app.js.

But there is something that I don't understand. In that file, my required files path are still the same than before...

Here is my gulpfile.js :

```
var gulp       = require("gulp");
var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
var babel      = require("gulp-babel");
var concat     = require("gulp-concat");
var resolveDependencies      = require("gulp-resolve-dependencies");

gulp.task("default", function () {
  return gulp.src("client/**/*.js")
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(concat("app.js"))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/js"));
});
```

As you can see, I want to concat nested folders.

Take a look for example at the top of my /client/components/app.js :

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import AppLeftNav from './AppLeftNav';
import {AppCanvas, AppBar, Styles} from 'material-ui';

//Code here
```

So in my app app.js generated by gulp, i can see :

```
var _AppLeftNav = require('./AppLeftNav');
```

It's a relative path and it can't work.

So, what's the tricks to handle theses required files with relative path ?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT : See the error I get :

```
Error: Cannot find module './components/App.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (MyFolder\dist\js\app.js:34:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

Answer (score 4):

To anyone who might have the same problem. Babel currently doesn't support  imports inlining [#1681](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1681), neither do gulp-concat, as it's just concatenating files.

I opted to use [Rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup) to propertly resolve dependencies and only then transpile output:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rollup = require('gulp-rollup');

gulp.task('build', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/parser-factory.js', { read: false })
    .pipe(rollup({ external: ['request', 'cheerio'] }))
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(babel({ stage: 0 }))
    .pipe(concat('realty-parser.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('lib'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The question was on my misunderstanding of gulp and Browserify. I've done what I wanted to with browserify (Concat and transpilation by one entry point, my app.js).

Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get it all in a single file then you will have to write `.pipe(gulp.dest("dist/js/jsfile.js"));` where **jsfile** is the name of your file.

Comment: Well, I have all already all file in one. But what about require and path are they parsed or something ? I'm not sure if i'm clear :/