# Babel compiled JS fails to import relative paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I have an npm package that I'm writing in ES2015 and transpiling with Babel 6. The ES2015 source code is in `/src`, split into modules in `/src/core`, `/src/commands`, and so on. As it is a CLI tool, the entry point is in `/src/bin/app.js`. If I run `babel-node src/bin/app.js` it works as expected.

Ideally, I'd like to install this tool globally (like `grunt-cli`), so I transpile the whole package to a single, valid JS (ES5) file with `babel src -o /lib/app.js`. However, if I try to run the file, it raises an error trying to require modules from relative paths, and these modules can't be found because they were all amalgamated into `app.js`. The error is:

```
$ node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js lib/app
module.js:328
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../commands/index'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/app/lib/app.js:19:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/me/dev/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:138:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
```

My `.babelrc` is simply:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Should this work, or do I need to configure Babel some more? The backup plan is to simply transpile the whole `/src` folder into `/lib` and publish everything, but a single file would be nicer.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963999/using-babel-with-a-single-output-file-and-es6-modules) with referenced answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873235/gulp-concat-and-require-path/33280669#33280669).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out [Babel doesn't support this at the moment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963999/using-babel-with-a-single-output-file-and-es6-modules). It simply concatenates files together, and hence relative path imports won't work.

Rather than using Babel with a path-resolving plugin, the solution is to use [Rollup](http://rollupjs.org/) with a [Babel plugin](https://github.com/rollup/babel-preset-es2015-rollup). I've created a [simple project](https://github.com/orlade/es2015-babel-rollup-demo) to test and demo the setup.